# Wilcoxon Test with Random Effect

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I would like to test if there is a significant difference in the speed of movement between 2 treatments for different females. For each female, I have several sampling points. I have a table with the female's ID (1st column), the speed for the first treatment (2nd column) and the speed for the second treatment (3rd column) (with several sampling points per female). 
I was thinking of doing a Wilcoxon test to test if there is a significant difference between the two treatments, but I need to add the random effect of the female's ID. 
I was told to apply a mixed model, but the result of the model only gives me if I have a linear relationship between the two, whereas I want to know if the two treatments are significantly different. 
Does anyone know how I can get this result?

Comment: Are you interested in individual performance or are you more interested in studying the effects of the treatments on the population as a whole?  Also, I'm not sure what this statement means:  "but the result of the model only gives me if I have a linear relationship between the two."  Can you clarify?  I think there might be an error in there somewhere.

Comment: I am interested in the effects of the treatments on the population as a whole. I did a linear mixed model between the 2 treatments, and I have a significant linear relationship between the 2, while I want to know if the 2 treatments are significantly different.